# Windows named pipe ReadFile failing with error 232

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, ipc, named-pipes

I have two 32 bit applications communicating over a named pipe in windows without errors.

Recently due to project requirements I had to convert one of the 32 bit to 64 bit application, Now when the 64 bit application is trying to read the data over named pipe it is giving the error 232. The 32 bit application write operation is successful checked with return value.

Can anybody with experience windows named pipe IPC guide me what could be going wrong.

I am attaching the code snippets of read and write operations below.

Pipe creation:

```
 `CString PipeNameStart = "\\\\.\\pipe\\local\\"+node->GetPipeName();
    tempHandle = CreateNamedPipe(PipeNameStart,
    PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND,
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_NOWAIT,
    1,
    node->GetPipeSize(),
    node->GetPipeSize(),
    0,
    NULL);
    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == tempHandle)
    {
     return FALSE;
    }
    node->SetPipeHandle(tempHandle);`
```

Write operation successful:

```
BOOL result;
unsigned long int amount;
CString pipename = node->GetPipeName();

result = WriteFile(node->GetPipeHandle(), //Handle to pipe
message, //buffer to write from
amountToSend, //size fo the buffer
&amount, //actual amount of bytes written
NULL); //not overlapped I/O

if(FALSE == result)
{
 *error = GetLastError();
}
```

Result is successful.

Read operation failure:

```
 BOOL result;
  CString pipename = node->GetPipeName();

  result = ReadFile(node->GetPipeHandle(),            //Handle to pipe
                    message,           //buffer to read too
                    bufferSize,               //size fo the buffer
                    amountInput, //actuall amount of bytes read
                    NULL);    //not overlapped I/O

  if(FALSE == result)
  {
    *error = GetLastError();
  }
  else
  {
     printf("Client Request String:%s\n", message);
  }
  return result;
```

Error is 232

I tried printing the pipe name at write and read location , both are same.
Printed the return value in write and it is successful. Read file is failing with error 232.

Comment: `232` is `ERROR_NO_DATA`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

Comment: How are you opening the pipe in the client? Are you using `CreateNamedPipe` in both applications? One should create, the other should open. Please show a [mre]

Comment: You are opening the pipe in `PIPE_NOWAIT` mode, and you are reading when there is no data to be read, without any attempt to wait or loop on this condition, so you are getting ERROR_NO_DATA. This is only to be expected. Why also are you opening it in `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE` mode? None of this makes much sense.

Answer (score 0):

`ERROR_NO_DATA` is what's causing error code 232 to appear on your system by closing the pipe before reading any data. A well-known culprit in these circumstances is communicating between two apps with different bit architectures using only one named pipe. When there are problems with sharing the handle correctly, such as keeping it open while processing or clearing it after use, issues like this can arise.

Some following approaches to your issue:

***Using a mutex to synchronize access to the named pipe***:

`Pros`: Ensures that only one process can access the named pipe at any given time, preventing race conditions.

`Cons`: May introduce performance overhead due to synchronization.

```cpp
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, _T("MyNamedPipeMutex"));
if (hMutex == NULL)
{
    // Handle error
}

// Synchronize access to the named pipe
WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);

// Perform read or write operation on the named pipe

ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
CloseHandle(hMutex);
```

***Using overlapped I/O with named pipes***:

`Pros`: Allows for asynchronous communication, which can improve performance.

`Cons`: May be more complex to implement.

```cpp
OVERLAPPED overlapped;
memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

// Perform read or write operation on the named pipe with overlapped I/O

DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
if (!GetOverlappedResult(node->GetPipeHandle(), &overlapped, &dwBytesTransferred, TRUE))
{
    // Handle error
}

CloseHandle(overlapped.hEvent);
```

***Ensure proper handle inheritance***:

`Pros`: Ensures that the pipe handle is correctly shared between the 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

`Cons`: May require changes to the process creation code.

Check the `bInheritHandle` params when creating the pipe to ensure that the handle can be inherited by the child process. Additionally, set the `lpStartupInfo` of `CreateProcess` to include the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag and set the `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput`, and `hStdError` fields to the desired pipe handles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time for writing a detailed reply.
I have tried the first two methods but it doesn't seem to show any effect. Will try the third method too.

Comment: Really? I suggest that when you open a pipe in PIPE_NOWAIT mode and read when there is no data to read, ERROR_NO_DATA is exactly what you should expect, regardless of 32/64-bit architecture.